# pdfjam pdfnup nup join line

Tags: pdf, printing, editing

I'm using pdfjam to imposition pages back together for artwork print. All works fine; however I'm getting a 1 pixel join line between the joined pages.

For example a simple 100x200 2 pager black: https://prnt.sc/jliua3

With this cmd:

```
pdfnup -q 2b.pdf --nup 2x1 --papersize '{200mm,200mm}' --outfile black-out2.pdf
```

Produces: https://prnt.sc/jlivot

Any idea how I stop it appearing or remove it?

Comment: sry pdfjam v2.08

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was importing the PDF into Photoshop with anti-aliasing turned on.

Turn off Anti-Aliasing and the line disappears.